# Guardar varias abas de um excel em uma lista ou array [python | pandas | numpy]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Estou importando uma base de dados que chega pra mim com várias abas, e o número de abas é aleatório. Estou tentando automatizar pra independente do número de abas o código funcionar de maneira automatizada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero tentar utilizar um for pois o processo que será feito em cada aba é o mesmo.

Cada aba tem o nome Table 1, Table 2 ... e assim consecutivamente daí o for serviria pra ir alterando de tabela em tabela(aba em aba)

Queria saber oque utilizar, se é um array, uma lista ou algo do gênero.
Depois de várias tentativas essa foi a minha ideia final, mas não sei aonde guardar esses dados

```
    import pandas as pd

    df_total = pd.read_excel('Consulta Fisioterapeuta 68 vagas.xlsx', None)
    table = []

    for x in range (1, len(df_total)+1:
        table[x] = pd.read_excel('Consulta Fisioterapeuta 68 vagas.xlsx', 'Table '+x)
```

Comment: Faça `table[x] = pd.read_excel('Consulta Fisioterapeuta 68 vagas.xlsx', 'Table ' + str(x) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, acho que entendi o que você quer e descobri a solução, porém ao tentar fazer mais ou menos o que você fez obtive o seguinte erro:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('playlist_tabela.xlsx', None)

table = []
for x in range (1, len(df)+1):
        table[x] = pd.read_excel('playlist_tabela.xlsx', 'Sheet'+str(x))

table
```

**ERRO**

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-294727c2966e> in <module>
     16 table = []
     17 for x in range (1, len(df)+1):
---> 18         table[x] = pd.read_excel('playlist_tabela.xlsx', 'Sheet'+str(x))
     19 
     20 table

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Para inserir itens em lista, no python usamos o método .append(). Veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

**Solução**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('playlist_tabela.xlsx', None)

table = []
for x in range (1, len(df)+1):
        table.append(pd.read_excel('playlist_tabela.xlsx', 'Sheet'+str(x)))

table
```

A saída é uma lista de dataframes.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).